# Gatsby deploy to github pages on mobile never loads images & hooks are not working

Tags: javascript, deployment, github-pages, gatsby

Recently I deployed my application to github-pages with gatsby deploy. On desktop everything works as intended, on localhost it has worked both on my mobile and my desktop.
Link to application: https://daria-marczak.github.io/renome/

I verified if it is only my phone's doing but unfortunately not. Everything seems to be working all right through localhost so I suspect something is not quite right with the deployment itself. It does use different command, as it builds instead of develops, but I'm not sure if it actually could cause the issue.

My package.json:

```
  "name": "renome",
  "private": true,
  "description": "renome restaurant",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Daria Marczak",
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.4.2",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.0.41",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.12",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.0.36",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.5.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.1.19",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "object-fit-images": "^3.2.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dates": "^20.2.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.4",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^4.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-eslint": "^2.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-stylelint": "^3.2.0",
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "husky": "^2.2.0",
    "lint-staged": "^8.1.6",
    "prettier": "^1.17.0",
    "stylelint": "^10.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^2.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "^0.1.1",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "^1.6.0",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^0.10.5"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public",
    "format": "prettier --write src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "dev-m": "gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0 -p 8000",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\""
  },
  "homepage": "https://daria-marczak.github.io/renome/"
}
```

My gatsby.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Renome',
    description:
      'Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.',
    author: '@dariamarczak',
  },
  pathPrefix: '/renome',
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    'gatsby-plugin-styled-components',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assets`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'posts',
        path: `${__dirname}/src/posts`,
      },
    },
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
      options: {
        name: 'gatsby-starter-default',
        short_name: 'starter',
        start_url: '/',
        background_color: '#663399',
        theme_color: '#663399',
        display: 'minimal-ui',
        icon: 'src/assets/icons/gatsby-icon.png',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-eslint',
      options: {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|cache|public)/,
        options: {
          emitWarning: true,
          failOnError: false,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        commonmark: true,
        footnotes: true,
        pedantic: true,
        gfm: true,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Now if I go to mobile version of deployed project, it practically doesn't work. The images that were loaded with gatsby-img have their blurred lines (not sure how to describe this loading effect) but they never fully load. Every single functionality that used useState() hook does not function at all and all buttons that have prevent defaults on them actually refresh the browser.

Comment: This looks identical on mobile and desktop.

Comment: Do you have images loading correctly? Can you open hamburger menu on mobile? What kind of phone did you use?

Comment: Desktop & Mobile: There are definitely errors and the images look to be stuck in their grey svg versions, burger menu does not open.

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/how-gatsby-works-with-github-pages/

Comment: yup. that's where I found about everything I need to configure in order to deploy...